# Laravel - Paginate with mysql Rand() and Seed

Tags: mysql, laravel, caching, queue

I am so close to giving up because I am stuck on this for quite a long time now.
I hope you can help me out.

**The Goal**

I want to return a *paginated and cached, query* in an infinite scroll.
I'm using Ajax to make calls from the View to the Controller and fetch the "nextPageUrl()" and save it in my view.

**The Problem**

My Query returns a randomized order of the inner arrays (which are sorted on the first level as well) which is great. But the query runs every time i make the ajax call,too. So i thought: hey, lets cache it so i have the same query every time i make the ajax call and i have no more duplicates. But duplicates appear with every ajax request i do..

**What i tried:**

Here is my query which gets cached and paginated:

```
$counter = $request->page;

$results = Cache::remember($counter, 1, function () {
    $seed = rand(1,9999);

    return Ad::where('status', 1)
        ->whereIn('ad_type', [0, 1, 2, 3])
        ->where('expire_at', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->where('special_ad', 'standard_ad')
        ->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(ad_type,2,1,3,0)"))
        ->inRandomOrder()
        ->paginate(15);
});


if($request->ajax()) {
    return [
        'ads' => view('partials.advanced_search_sidebar2')->with(compact('results','index'))->render(),
        'next_page' => $results->nextPageUrl(),
    ];
} else {
    return view("welcome_live", compact('results', 'usertypes'));
}
```

The **inRandomOrder();** method is laravels equivalent to **orderByRaw("RAND()")**

I found the following which unfortunately does not work as it should for me:
[Laravel Random Pagination Cache](https://laravel.io/forum/03-22-2014-random-pagination-cache)

I do not want to write out too much because it can be confusing having a wall of code here, if you need a more thorough explanation of the code or some more code snippets or my "way of handling things explained" please let me know.
Thank you in advance for your support.
Regards, Desory.

Edit:: I tried using the $seed as an argument in the inRandomOrder($seed) but this returned the same query over and over even though the seed was different.

**Somewhat closer to the solution**
I have tried using a fixed $seed value, in my case i just typed in 25
so the seed is always 25, no more duplicates , great, but the order is always the same now.
I basically feel like i can choose between having a random order and duplicates, and having the same order but no duplicates..

**My Ajax Function**

```
function renderBase() {
    var page = $('.suchergebnisWrapper').data("base");
    var counter = $('.suchergebnisWrapper').data("counter");


    if (counter < 10) {
        $.ajax({
            url: page,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
            },
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
            },
        }).done(
            function (responseData) {
                $('.resultwrapper').append(responseData.ads);
                $('.suchergebnisWrapper').data('base', responseData.next_page);

            });
    }

}
```

It might seem confusing because in the Controller I am using "counter" and in javascript,too , but this is just to have a different "key" in my cache everytime.

Comment: For me, you should define your `$seed` in the user session, to always use the same `$seed` for a given user. In your example, everytime you cache your query, you get a new `$seed`, so a new order. And then, are you sure you pass a `page` parameter in your ajax call ?

Comment: I will try storing the seed in the user session, thanks for that advice. A new order is what i get when i run this query exactly this is what i need. everytime the cache resets a new order shall appear. i will post my ajax function in the edit of my initial question. Thanks for you help so far Vincent Decaux.

Comment: I can't see any way of achieving what you desire in a simple manner. Since you want always random ordering, you can't use Laravel Pagination in any meaningful way, because the purpose of pagination is to split up a result set into smaller chunks that can be displayed at a time. But randomizing the results essentially ensures that sooner or later you will get duplicates because the paginator doesn't know what your query does and just does it's job of returning a chunk.

Comment: Exactly bodgan, that is why I tried caching the query so its always the same and only changes when its content changes (some user posts a post or the cache time runs out)

Comment: To avoid duplicates but keep the random nature of your results in an infinite scroll page, the query that is executed each time a result set chunk is returned, should know to exclude already rendered results. While this seems simple as a concept, each time you cache more identifiers (or whatever data you need) to filter out the already rendered results, your query would inevitably get slower since it would need to filter out a bigger and bigger result set.

Comment: You mean by , for example, sending and storing the ids and excluding them, I thought about that, but I will only go for it if my approach does not work. I dont like giving up at all so I really want this to work.

Comment: I can't see any other logical way to ensure there are no duplicates returned and still run a random query every single time. Your query **must** contain some sort of condition that prevents duplication when the query is run. The obvious way are the identifiers and perhaps some other strategies could be found for particular cases, but trying to cache your query results doesn't seem logical for this particular issue.

Comment: Let me summarize my thoughts: Running a Query returns a Result, which should be for this case , reusable. So i "save" it in a cache and can do whatever i want with it in the remaining time the cache holds on. The query only returns duplicates because rand() is getting called or? with a fixed seed the problem dissolves and my query is unique , but the order is always the same. with a variable seed the order is perfectly random but duplicates appear , jesus what a hard rock this query is. What about vincents approach @bogdan?

Comment: @VincentDecaux's approach is actually very good, I've missed the first comment somehow :). I'd say go for it, as it does offer randomness but allows for consistency within the pagination result sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

distinct() can give you not duplication of data you should pass the attribute like id in it

```
return Ad::where('status', 1)
    ->whereIn('ad_type', [0, 1, 2, 3])
    ->where('expire_at', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    ->where('special_ad', 'standard_ad')
    ->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(ad_type,2,1,3,0)"))
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->distinct()
    ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Great Idea indeed, but i have tried that already. if it were a static query it would work perfectly, but it is very dynamically, saying, the query could look like: [1,2,4,3,10] and in the next run [10,100,291,3,1]. I do not really know why distinct doesnt work as it should , tbh, but it didnt thats all i know. I appreciate your effort trying to help me.

Answer (score -1):

try this after $counters->appends(Input::except('page'));

Comment: My apologies, where exactly do you mean :)?

Comment: @Dinesh Bajgain Answers should contain explanations. Pasting a line of code is not really useful and considered to be very low quality.

Comment: before returning the value in view

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the problem. Not the entire page gets duplicated, but some results in my query are getting duplicated because of the randomness.

Comment: this line of code append the data and delete previous pagination link

Comment: Can you give me a small example of how this works? I am currently storing the page in a data- attribute.